# Spring MVC error No validator could be found for type

Tags: spring, controller

I'm having this error when I try persist a Task class with a join column

This is my join column on Task model

```
    @NotEmpty
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="project_id")
    private Project project;
```

And this is the controller request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public String addTask(@Valid Task task, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, HttpServletResponse response) {
        //TODO
        task.setProject(service.findById(1).getProject()); 

        List<String> errors = service.save(task);
        if(errors != null) {
            model.addAttribute("errors", errors);
            response.setStatus(500);
            return "alertErrors";
        }

        model.addAttribute("tasks", service.findGrid(null));
        return "tasks/listTable";
    }
```

But when I call the controller they return me a error **No validator could be found for type: ...model.Project.**. 
I'm already put the error on messages and add **headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** to method but still returning error.

What I'm nees to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Hibernate Validator documentation you cannot add @NotEmpty on your custom property - it should be used with Strings, Arrays, Collections etc...

You probably should use: javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.